# Button click popup a new window

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access-2007

I want to know that, on a button click, a popup window should display collecting the user type  from the database. From that window, we can select one usertype and that will fill in the textbox nearby the button. I am using an MS Access database and user_master table from which I am getting the usertype.

Comment: Please post any code you have for this.  The question is a bit confusing as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this :

Let's say you have a textbox (`choiceTxtBox`) where the user inputs the choice to pick form database.

```
thatButton.Click += (the, game) => 
{
   db = new OleDbConnection();
   db.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" + fileName;
   db.Open();

   string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE SomeField = @UserChoice";

   cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, db);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserChoice", choiceTxtBox.Text);
   rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (rdr.Read())
   resultTxtBox.Text += ((string)rdr["GroupName"]);
};
```

Comment: Don't create SQL queries by concatting strings.  I don't care if you know about it or not; including such code in an answer *will* result in it being emulated, even if you tell people not to leave it as is.

Comment: No one that uses a Megaman villain (or an SNES controller for that matter) as their avatar on SO is 'lazy'.  NOTE:  this is just my opinion :P

Comment: i m having the texbox for usertype in the Access.aspx page and a button near the textbox whenever i will click a button a popup window containing all usertypes from my user_master should be displayed . I ahould be able to select a usertype from that window .after selecting the usertype from popup window that value should be displayed in texbox in my access.aspx page

Comment: Note that your code is also blocking the UI thread for the duration of the query.

Comment: @Servy why? Can you explain ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk In the click event handler of a button you're executing a database request and performing a blocking wait on the result, rather than using asynchrony to avoid blocking the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy You're right bad practice. I shall learn from this thanks

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Well, it's more than just a bad practice.  It results in a completely horrible user experience.

Comment: @Servy *horrible user experience* implying the query is big enough to make a difference. But still thanks I won't use this method again.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Even the most basic of queries are generally long enough for the UI blocking to be noticable to the user.  On top of that you can have less than ideal cases such as connection issues, or other error cases that result in the query taking much longer than normal.  You want to keep the program working but show some indication of the problem to the user, not freeze the application.